# cy.exec timeout with backgrounded process

Tags: python, testing, cypress

I'm trying to start a server using `cy.exec`and background the process like so:

```
cy.exec('nohup python -m my_module arg_1 &', { failOnNonZeroExit: false }).then(result => {
    if (result.code != 0) {
      throw new Error(`Execution of "${command}" failed
      Exit code: ${result.code}
      Stdout:\n${result.stdout}
      Stderr:\n${result.stderr}`);
    }
  })
```

This, however, causes the timeout error as if the process was running in the foreground. I realize that starting the server with `cy.exec` is an antipattern but I have a very peculiar case where I need to start a server with different parameters for every test.
I thought that by backgrounding the process I could circumvent the timeout requirement of `cy.exec`.

If that is not an option, though, what would be the best practice for this scenario i.e. starting a different server per cypress test?

Comment: Are you aiming to start the server with certain parameters on ci?

Comment: @jjhelguero no, I actually need to modify the way the server is started to test different functionalities. In other words, I need start the server with a different parameters per cypress spec and then kill it once the spec has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with cypress task instead of "cy.exce"

Example
within your cypress/plugins/index.js

```
const startServer = async function (ExecuteCommandWithPath) {
    
    exec(ExecuteCommandWithPath,
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
};
```

```
module.exports = ( on, config ) => {
  on("task", {
PythonServerStatUp(ExecuteCommandWithPath) {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                startServer(ExecuteCommandWithPath);
                resolve(false);
            });
        },
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It does trigger Python process but the currentl problem is that Python's virtual environment fom the original bash script is not propagated so Python process crashes.
I've tried passing `process.env`explicitly using `spawn`in place of `exec` but it doesn't work. Check the updated version #2 in my quesiton (thanks!)

Comment: Actually, the env error was related to another problem and the solution suggested works! Updating the question and accepting the answer.

Comment: Any idea how this would work in Cypress 10+?
index.js is not supported anymore and when i try to integrate it in the cypress.config.ts i get an error which states that exec is not recognized.